# Fourier Transform with array

Tags: python, arrays, fft

I'm trying to define a Fourier Transform for an array in Python. [The formula I'm trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MTYk.png).

However, the output is always an empty array. Could you help me fix my error ?

```
import numpy as np
def TF(T):
    N = len(T)
    Tr = np.array([])
    for k in range(0,N-1):
        Tl = 0
        for l in range(0,N-1):
            Tk += (T[l])*np.exp((-2j*np.pi*k*l)/N)
        np.append(Tr,Tk)
    print('Tr =',Tr)

TF(np.array([2,3,5,7,2,9]))
```

Comment: As posted it will always return `None`, you need to add a `return` statement at the end of your function.  It also raises an exception:  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Tk' referenced before assignment`

Comment: The print shows an empty array so a return statement would not be the full solution.

Comment: In general, loops should be avoided when working with NumPy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **You need to store the results.`np.append` works in-place.**
2. **You code needs changes**.

Use this:

```
import numpy as np

def TF(T):
    N = len(T)
    results = []
    for k in range(N): # this goes from 0 to N-1
        Tk = 0 # Tk here
        for l in range(N): # this goes from 0 to N-1
            Tk += (T[l])*np.exp((-2j*np.pi*k*l)/N)
        results.append(Tk) # store the result
    return np.array(results) # return the results

T = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9])

TF(T)
array([ 28. +0.00000000e+00j,  -2.5+2.59807621e+00j,
        -0.5+7.79422863e+00j, -10. -2.22329102e-14j,
        -0.5-7.79422863e+00j,  -2.5-2.59807621e+00j])
```

Comment: Should the result not be the same dimension as the input? From the formula, the $k^{th}$ component of the transform is given and the function iterates over $k$ on the range (0, N-1]

Comment: Is there really no vectorized solution for this? We’re stuck looping and appending?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this but the OP did not ask for an optimized version. Instead the OP needs a correct implementation. Cheers Alexander

Comment: This solution is not correct! The final answer does not coincide with previously implemented FFT functions.

Comment: Edited after founding the second error in OPs code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on the for loop, I'm not very familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error somewhere else in your original formulation of the function, I have slightly modified it to be vectorized and compared it against the official numpy FFT function:

```py
def TF(T):
    N = len(T)
    idx = np.arange(N)
    Tr = np.empty(shape=T.shape, dtype=np.complex)
    for k in idx:
        Tr[k] = np.sum(T*np.exp((-2j*np.pi*k*idx)/N))

    return Tr
```

Comparing to `np.fft.fft()`:

```py
x = np.array([2,3,5,7,2,9])

custom_fft = TF(x)
numpy_fft = np.fft.fft(x)

np.allclose(custom_fft, numpy_fft)
>>> True
```

Always check against a known solution when performing sanity checks on your code! It will save you many many times :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The goal of my subject was to build a FFT only with np.exp and np.pi. That's why I didn't use any other np function.